# "Undo" not working in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to use Blender for video editing, but for  some reason the "Undo" function isn't working on the video sequence editor. It works fine on any other mode, though.

Is this by design or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it your trying to undo?

Comment: any operation at all in the VSE. In other modes Undo works normally.

I tried resetting to factory defaults, but nothing worked. I eventually discovered the problem was only on that specific .blend file, so I copied everything over to a new file and "solved" the problem.

I still have no idea what actually caused it, though.

Comment: Sounds like a bug

Answer (score 3):

The "Undo" doesn't work unless you have set the "Default mode" to "Object mode" vs. "Edit mode" (vertices) in the 3D view. Of odd reasons this setting also applies to the "Video Sequence Editor".

Comment: This actually worked for me. Wasn't expecting it to but it did. Quirky config setup.